# Может ли pyrogram сохранять какие-то данные в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, pyrogram

Мне нужно что-бы юзербот записывал в файл несколько значений как это сделать, библиотека pyrogram.

Comment: А при чём тут pyrogram? Возможность записи файлов встроена в питон и описана в любом учебнике https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ в любом учебнике https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html например тут

Comment: “Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”